# mysql: get data from latest column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+-------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+
| color                         | code          | date                |
+-------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+
| red                           |           300 | 2017-06-23 11:44:14 |
| red                           |           600 | 2017-06-23 11:37:14 |
| green                         |           200 | 2017-06-23 09:08:59 |
| green                         |           200 | 2017-06-23 09:06:59 |
| yellow                        |             0 | 2017-06-21 09:23:43 |
| blue                          |           100 | 2017-06-21 09:13:36 |
| blue                          |           105 | 2017-06-21 09:12:36 |
| red                           |           200 | 2017-06-21 09:11:05 |
| green                         |           200 | 2017-06-21 09:09:46 |
| yellow                        |           900 | 2017-06-21 09:01:04 |
| blue                          |           400 | 2017-06-21 08:50:50 |
| blue                          |           400 | 2017-06-21 08:50:30 |
| red                           |           700 | 2017-06-21 08:49:52 |
| red                           |           800 | 2017-06-21 08:49:03 |
| green                         |           500 | 2017-06-20 20:15:29 |
| yellow                        |           200 | 2017-06-20 19:31:47 |
| blue                          |           300 | 2017-06-20 19:15:02 |
| blue                          |           300 | 2017-06-19 19:20:02 |
+-------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

I need a query which creates a table showing the total amount of each color from the color column and also show the most recent code and date for each color.

The closest I've got so far is with this query:

```
SELECT color, 
max(code) AS code, 
max(date) AS date, 
count(*) AS count 
FROM checks 
GROUP BY color 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 12;
```

This is almost perfect except the code column displays the highest number and not the most recent code. So for yellow code would be 900 when it should be 0 because 0 is the most recent.

Example table for the above query:

```
     +---------------------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+
    | color                     | code          | date                | count |
    +---------------------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+
    | blue                      |           400 | 2017-06-21 09:13:36 |     6 |
    | red                       |           800 | 2017-06-23 11:44:14 |     5 |
    | green                     |           500 | 2017-06-23 09:08:59 |     4 |
    | yellow                    |           900 | 2017-06-21 09:23:43 |     3 |
    +---------------------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+
```

If I change `max(code)` to just `code` then it gets the first code instead so the code for yellow would be 200.

I need the results table to look like this:

```
+---------------------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+
| color                     | code          | date                | count |
+---------------------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+
| blue                      |           100 | 2017-06-21 09:13:36 |     6 |
| red                       |           300 | 2017-06-23 11:44:14 |     5 |
| green                     |           200 | 2017-06-23 09:08:59 |     4 |
| yellow                    |             0 | 2017-06-21 09:23:43 |     3 |
+---------------------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Thanks :)

Comment: latest *row*???

Comment: most recent date would be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select t.*, the_table.code  from the_table
inner join
(select color, count(*), max(date) as maxdate from the_table group by color)t
on the_table.color = t.color and the_table.date = t.maxdate
```

Comment: Yep - although personally I think it's simpler and more intuitive to grab the columns (except count) from `the_table`, so: `select the_table.*, t.total from..(..count(*) total...)...`

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes, may be